# Rename a file using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I wish to read a file from a url and create a download stream with a different file name using nodejs on lambda.

Currently I am trying but failing with this code.

```
var fs= require('fs');

var url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png";
fs.rename(url, "download.png", function(err) {
  if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`fs.rename` should be used for renaming the local file.

In your case, you would like to download a file from external URL and save it to new name, you can try this solution instead

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("download.png");
var request = http.get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Comment: Getting this error : Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'download.png' at Error (native)

Comment: Just remember you are working on Lambda and it only allows you to write to the /tmp directory